# Laravel how create sort + search scope

Tags: php, laravel, scope

i want to create scope , but dont know how to create it because my code kinda kinky :d, code will be below. Can you show me example for my 1-2 sort requests which will work with search too? (i want to get this). Basic functional is like this -> i have searching form, which is searching between countries, also i can sort this countries by arrow buttons, by desc or asc, (first one is by country names sorting, and others is only numbers), im able now to sort correctly, and also search and then sort.
CONTROLLER :

```
    $countries = Country::latest()->filter(request(['search']))->get();
    $infos = Info::all();
    $page = request('page');
    $confirmed = Info::sum('confirmed');
    $recovered = Info::sum('recovered');
    $deaths = Info::sum('deaths');

    //for by country name sorting

    if (request()->get('sort') === 'country_desc')
    {
        $countries = Country::orderByDesc(Info::select('country')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))->get();
        if (request()->get('search'))
        {
            $countries = Country::orderByDesc(Info::select('country')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))
                ->latest()->filter(request(['search']))->get();
        }
    }
    if (request()->get('sort') === 'country_asc')
    {
        $countries = Country::orderBy(Info::select('country')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))->get();
        if (request()->get('search'))
        {
            $countries = Country::orderBy(Info::select('country')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))
                ->latest()->filter(request(['search']))->get();
        }
    }

    //   for new cases sorting
    if (request()->get('sort') === 'cases_desc')
    {
        $countries = Country::orderByDesc(Info::select('confirmed')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))->get();
        if (request()->get('search'))
        {
            $countries = Country::orderByDesc(Info::select('confirmed')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))
                ->latest()->filter(request(['search']))->get();
        }
    }
    if (request()->get('sort') === 'cases_asc')
    {
        $countries = Country::orderBy(Info::select('confirmed')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))->get();
        if (request()->get('search'))
        {
            $countries = Country::orderBy(Info::select('confirmed')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))
                ->latest()->filter(request(['search']))->get();
        }
    }

    // for deaths sorting
    if (request()->get('sort') === 'deaths_desc')
    {
        $countries = Country::orderByDesc(Info::select('deaths')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))->get();
        if (request()->get('search'))
        {
            $countries = Country::orderByDesc(Info::select('deaths')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))
                ->latest()->filter(request(['search']))->get();
        }
    }
    if (request()->get('sort') === 'deaths_asc')
    {
        $countries = Country::orderBy(Info::select('deaths')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))->get();
        if (request()->get('search'))
        {
            $countries = Country::orderBy(Info::select('deaths')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))
                ->latest()->filter(request(['search']))->get();
        }
    }

    //for recovered sorting
    if (request()->get('sort') === 'recovered_desc')
    {
        $countries = Country::orderByDesc(Info::select('recovered')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))->get();
        if (request()->get('search'))
        {
            $countries = Country::orderByDesc(Info::select('recovered')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))
                ->latest()->filter(request(['search']))->get();
        }
    }
    if (request()->get('sort') === 'recovered_asc')
    {
        $countries = Country::orderBy(Info::select('recovered')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))->get();
        if (request()->get('search'))
        {
            $countries = Country::orderBy(Info::select('recovered')->whereColumn('infos.country_id', 'countries.id'))
                ->latest()->filter(request(['search']))->get();
        }
    }
```

COUNTRY MODEL SCOPE :

```
public function scopeFilter($query, array $filters)
{
    $query->when($filters['search'] ?? false, fn ($query, $search) => $query
    ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%'));
}
```

as you can see its kinda big code, so i want to create scopes or etc.. what is the best way to reduce this code